# Magento 2 upgrade 2.3

Tags: magento2, upgrade, composer

Currently trying to upgrade to the newest magento 2.3 using a script.
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html
Whenever I type:

```
php -f pre_composer_update_2.3.php -- --root='<path/to/magento/install/dir>' --repo=https://repo.magento.com/ <options>
```

I get:
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

After root I would type '/home/something/public_html/' --repo blabla.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The characters '<', and '>', are to indicate a place-holder, you should remove them to read**

Comment: It didn't work. Still getting same syntax error. im replacing <path/to/magento/install/dir> with /home/something/public_html/

Comment: also remove in <options> like this => '<' ,'>'